# How to use "fit" to frame the nodes and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, fit

I'm using the `fit` TikZ library to fit a rectangle around two nodes which include `label`s. However, the rectangle is only fit around the actual nodes, not about their labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\node [label=label1,draw] (node1) {Node1};
\node [label=label2,draw] (node2) at (4,2){Node2};

\node[fit=(node1)(node2), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to fit the rectangle also around the node labels?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}       
\node [label=label1,draw] (node1) {Node1};
\node [label={[name=l] label2},draw] (node2) at (4,2){Node2};    
\node[fit=(node1)(l), draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The other possibility is to avoid `label` and to create the label with a simple node outside (node2).

Comment: +1, but I would use `fit=(node1)(node2)(l1)(l2)` just to be at the save side. The labels might change later and be wider then the nodes etc.

Comment: Yes Martin, you are right !