# How to Automatically Resize Shape Around Nodes

Tags: resize, tikz-shape

I am using a Venn diagram to illustrate a functional relationship between two finite sets. Depending on the number of elements in the set, the ellipse I'm using may not include all the elements (and their labels). How can I adjust the following code to get the ellipses to automatically resize to include all the nodes and their labels?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
              every node/.style={on grid},
              setA/.style={fill=blue,circle,inner sep=2pt},
              setB/.style={fill=red,circle,inner sep=2pt},
              every fit/.style={draw,fill=blue!15,ellipse,text width=30pt},
              >=latex
            ]

            % set A
            \node[setA,label=left:$x$] (x) {};
            \node [setA,below = of x,label=left:$y$] (y) {};
            \node [setA,below = of y,label=left:$z$] (z) {};
            \node[above=of x,anchor=south] {$A$};

            % set B
            \node[setB,label=right:$10$,right=3cm of x] (10) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$20$, below = of 10] (20) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$30$,below = of 20] (30) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$40$,below = of 30] (40) {};
            \node[above=of 10,anchor=south] {$B$};

            % the arrows
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (x) -- node[label=above:$f$] {} (10);
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (y) -- node[] {} (10);
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (z) -- node[] {} (30);

            % the boxes around the sets
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[fit= (x)  (z) ] {};
            \node[fit= (10) (30) ] {};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to name the label and add it in the "fit"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
              every node/.style={on grid},
              setA/.style={fill=blue,circle,inner sep=2pt},
              setB/.style={fill=red,circle,inner sep=2pt},
              every fit/.style={draw,fill=blue!15,ellipse,text width=30pt},
              >=latex
            ]

            % set A
            \node[setA,label=left:$x$] (x) {};
            \node [setA,below = of x,label=left:$y$] (y) {};
            \node [setA,below = of y,label=left:$z$] (z) {};
            \node[above=of x,anchor=south,name=A] {$A$};

            % set B
            \node[setB,label=right:$10$,right=3cm of x] (10) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$20$, below = of 10] (20) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$30$,below = of 20] (30) {};
            \node[setB,label=right:$40$,below = of 30] (40) {};
            \node[above=of 10,anchor=south] {$B$};

            % the arrows
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (x) -- node[label=above:$f$] {} (10);
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (y) -- node[] {} (10);
            \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (z) -- node[] {} (30);

            % the boxes around the sets
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[fit= (x)  (z)  (A)] {};
            \node[fit= (10) (30) ] {};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

see [How to use "fit" to frame the nodes and labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/how-to-use-fit-to-frame-the-nodes-and-labels)

[image]

Comment: The label $A$ must be outside side of the ellipse, but the element labeled 40 must be inside the ellipse. However, I see what you mean about "fit". I got the element 40 to be inside. Thanks!